# Overlap views in android

Tags: android, android-image, overlap

I want to check if two views are overlapping in Android.
I'm using this code but viewsOverlap returns false everytime (the views are changing position)

```
public boolean viewsOverlap(View v1,View v2) {
    Rect R1=new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
    Rect R2=new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());
    return R1.intersect(R2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
return R1.contains(R2);
```

See the documention here: 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#cont...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains%28android.graphics.Rect%29)

or

```
return Rect.intersects(R1, R2);
```

See the documention here: 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#int...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)